# Asp.net convert textbox input to upper case on key down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to convert the text in a textbox to uppercase as the user writes it.

Html/aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="mytextbox" onkeydown="toUpperCase()"></asp:TextBox>
```

jQuery

```
function toUpperCase() {
    $(this.val) = this.val.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: try use `$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());`

Comment: Already tried, not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code that fulfils your requirement. We provided all code to change upper case on key down and key up. You can use both html and Asp control for that.

```js
function toUpperCase(ctrl) {
    $(ctrl).val($(ctrl).val().toUpperCase());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Enter value to change per character:-</td><td><input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="toUpperCase(this);" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter value to change previous character:- </td><td><input type="text" id="txt2" onkeydown="toUpperCase(this);" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like `$(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());`

Also you could just use pure css.

```
 #mytextbox{
    text-transform:uppercase;
 }
```

```js
$('#mytextbox').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="mytextbox"></textarea>
```

Comment: The thing is I want to use this function for multiple textboxes and If i use pure css, it only changes the visual, the value is still lower case